# need to create multiple record without each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a table, JobTypePresetting where i find few columns not null

```
jtp = JobTypePresetting.arel_table
JobTypePresetting.where(jtp[:comment_text_id].not_eq(nil).or(jtp[: part_listing_id].not_eq(nil)))
```

and i get few records and i need to create this records as duplicate in other table

so i find presettings id in other table like

```
avl_presetting_ids = JobEntry.where(job_id: params["job_id"], job_type_id: params["job_type_id"], template_id: params["template_id"]).pluck(:job_type_presetting_id)
```

and i match and create record if presetting id is not available like

```
  unless avl_presetting_ids.include?(presetting.id)
    JobEntry.create(job_id: params["job_id"], job_type_id: params["job_type_id"], template_id: params["template_id"],
                    job_type_presetting_id: presetting.id, comment_text_id: presetting.comment_text_id, part_listing_id: presetting.part_listing_id,
                    quantity: presetting.quantity, price: presetting.price, extension: presetting.extension)
  end
```

This happens in controller before loading, so many sql queries are being written in log. How to make this a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert) gem.

Use batch mode. You don't have to find `avl_presetting_ids` if there is a unique index on `job_type_presetting_id` column. Duplicated record will be ignored.

```
jtp = JobTypePresetting.arel_table
presettings = JobTypePresetting.where(
    jtp[:comment_text_id].not_eq(nil).
        or(jtp[:part_listing_id].not_eq(nil))
)

job_attr = JobEntry.new.attributes.symbolize_keys

Upsert.batch(JobEntry.connection, JobEntry.table_name) do |upsert|
  presettings.each do |presetting|
    attr = job_attr.merge(job_id: params["job_id"],
                          job_type_id: params["job_type_id"],
                          template_id: params["template_id"],
                          job_type_presetting_id: presetting.id,
                          comment_text_id: presetting.comment_text_id,
                          part_listing_id: presetting.part_listing_id,
                          quantity: presetting.quantity,
                          price: presetting.price,
                          extension: presetting.extension)
    upsert.row(attr)
  end
end
```

**Note**: be careful if you have callbacks in the model.

Or you can use `sidekiq` or `rescue` to run this in background.